# Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls

Tags: 2016, page-layout

I have SharePoint error in custom page layout

I checked this issue in SP logs and found this

> Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.
>    at System.Web.UI.FileLevelPageControlBuilder.AppendLiteralString(String text)
>    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessLiteral()

Comment: Somewhere in your page, you are using an element which is not allowed. Best you post the relevant part of your page so we can see what may be wrong.

Comment: If you share the markup for the page layout we will be able to help better.

Comment: Yes its working fine now  I changed the content place holder elements from <asp:content> to <asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is correct that only content tags can be added in those sections.

I have seen issues where the Content tag is all lower case like

```
<asp:content ....>
```

when infact it should be uppercase e.g

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
```

Comment: Hahaha, how to get answers, check the comments!!!

Comment: Yes you are right :)